# Get cell value from Google sheet for sending form results.

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to extract a value from a sheet field. The sheet is being populated by a form. I am using it to differentiate an email address to send the form results to. The script works, but the way I'm trying to extract the value of the field is not working.

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var branch = s.getRange(s.getLastRow(),s.getLastColumn(),1,1).getValue();

if (branch == 'Albany') {
    var email = "EMAIL ADDRESS"
    } else {
    var email = "OTHER EMAIL ADDRESS"
    }
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: When you use `getValue()` (without S at the end) you don't need to specify 4 parameters, the 2 first ones are sufficient.
  `var branch = s.getRange(s.getLastRow(),s.getLastColumn()).getValue();`

But it does not cause any error... what problem are you having exactly ?

Comment: Thanks for the info about getValue(). 

The branch variable never gets populated. If i debug, I see no value in that variable. I am receiving emails, but never to the positive part of the if, only the else.

Comment: A resolution! For some reason, the s.getLastColumn() function was returning a column after the last column. I'm not sure if this is in the way the form is writing to the sheet, but I was able to set s.getLastColumn() - 1 and it populates the value from the column i'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try use trigger "onFormSubmit" with e parameter. 
Link to article: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

I'm using this triggers every day.
My sample code:
`function sendNotyfication(e) {
var HTMLMessage = "my html message to send; var mail_adres; 
  if(e['values'] != undefined){

```
var items = e['namedValues'];
var items_sort = []; 
for(var i in items) {
  var item = [i, items[i]]
  items_sort.push(item);
}
items_sort.sort();
for(var j=0;j<items_sort.length;j++){
    HTMLMessage += '<p><b>'+items_sort[j][0]+'</b>: '+ items_sort[j][1]+'</p>'
}

//i have mail in my form
if(items['your question in form'][0] == 'xxxx'){
   mail_adres = "xxxx@domain.com"
}
```

}catch(e){}

```
HTMLMessage += "Hellol"
if(mail_adres!=null){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: mail_adres,
    bcc: bcc,
    noReply: true,
    subject: "New subject",
    htmlBody: HTMLMessage
  });
```

}`